# How can I remove values before a space in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to remove values before a space, since the numbers before the space don't belong there.
[image]

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors. What code have you tried for this already? Please [edit] your question. What happens when you run the code? What did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? See [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can try:

```
df.index = df.index.str.rsplit(' ', n=1).str[-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking something like following. Following will give us the result as 396.

```
'222 396'.split(' ', 1)[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also use list comprehensions:

```
i = df.index.to_list()
df.index = [j.split(' ',1)[1] for j in i]
```